# Getting a $scope.object to update once a PATCH has been successfully completed with Restangular

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, restangular

I have an object in a list. Call it $scope.contact

I do a PATCH to the end point and it returns successfully. However, I can't figure out how to update the $scope.contact with the new information.

This is my first full app, so I'm sure I'm making a stupid mistake. Feel free to link to docs I missed or a principle I'm not getting.

Here is my controller so far:

```
contactControllers.controller('ContactDetailController', ['$scope', 'growl', 'Restangular', function($scope, growl, Restangular) {

    $scope.editContact = function() {
        Restangular.one('contacts', $scope.contact.id).patch($scope.contact).then(function(contact) {
            $scope.contact = contact;

            // I can't figure out what is supposed to go here.
            // If I do .push(contact) I get undefined errors.

            growl.addSuccessMessage("Your contact was edited!");
        },function(response) {
            console.log('Error with status code: ', response.status);
        });
    }

}])
```

Comment: It looks like $object would help, but then it doesn't look like there is a good way to catch errors, or do anything conditional upon success. If $object IS the right way, how would one error check or do conditionals?

Comment: Ok. $object isn't right, That is an array by default.

Answer (score 0):

Update: since it is not an array and it is an object and this i the controller method
 Then wrap scope.vontact = contact eith apply method like this

```
$scope.$apply(function() {
     $scope.contact=contact;

});
```

So the complete controller would be

```
contactControllers.controller('ContactDetailController', ['$scope', 'growl', 'Restangular', function($scope, growl, Restangular) {

$scope.editContact = function() {
    Restangular.one('contacts', $scope.contact.id).patch($scope.contact).then(function(contact) {
 $scope.$apply(function () {
        $scope.contact = contact;
 });

        // I can't figure out what is supposed to go here.
        // If I do .push(contact) I get undefined errors.

        growl.addSuccessMessage("Your contact was edited!");
    },function(response) {
        console.log('Error with status code: ', response.status);
    });
}

}])
```

Comment: It's not an array. It's an object. That's why I use Restangular.one - it's just the one object. Your example works great (with push or call) for a list, but that's not what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Further, and possibly unrelated, but when I do set an array first, I get un-allowed method, which I believe is due to the fact that it's trying to send and array to an object and if you set it to an array and then do the .one on $scope.contact.id it's now empty because you reset it.

Comment: If both are objects then do not reset it, if you getting contact then anf it is not getting the scope.contact upfated then their is a way which i will update in the answer

Comment: Using apply gives me a digest already in progress error. After reading this article: http://jimhoskins.com/2012/12/17/angularjs-and-apply.html that error makes sense cause the $apply is already happening with the form submit event.

Comment: Oh ok....then we would need to create an angular factory and wrap the restangular call in it and in the callback then assign it